# Pdf to Html (+ javascript)

Tags: html, pdf

On our current site we offer our clients some brochures as pdf.
To keep our interaction in-site we were advised to use a conversion tool that converts pdf to flash.
Such a flash utility is basically an slideshow with some fancy effects and buttons.
This looks like a job jquery (or other frameworks) have mastered by now. There are a metric ton of jquery slider plugins.

Is there an existing solution that we can offer our marketing team that accepts a pdf and converts it to a (jquery) slider?

**EDIT**
The functionality should somehow be integrated in our Drupal content management interface so our Marketing and Communication department can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageMagick to convert a pdf to a bunch of images, then feed those images to a (jquery) slider anyway you want.

Comment: Yes, was thinking something along that way. It needs to be used by our MarCom departement as an integrated part of our Drupal site. If we are going to do any custom development this would probably something to check out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a PDF2HTML conversion tool, you could also have a look at our new Java app to do this [pdf_to_html_conversion](http://www.jpedal.org/pdf_to_html_conversion.php).